# Automatic adding thumbnail to post

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have got following code.

```
 $postData = array(
   'post_category' => array(get_category_id("website")),
   'post_content' => 'My website about cars.',
   'post_title' => 'my little cars',
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'tags_input' => 'cars, hobbies'
  );
  $pID = wp_insert_post($postData);
  update_post_meta($pID, "language", "English");
  update_post_meta($pID, "author", "John");
```

And how I can add a post thumbnail? Code written below is incorrect.

```
 $filename = "http://damianc.pl/th.jpg";
 $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
 $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
 $attachment = array(
  'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $filename ), 
  'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
  'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => 'inherit'
 );
 $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $pID );
 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
 $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
 wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Path to image is well. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$fileurl = "http://damianc.pl/th.jpg";
$filename = $upload_dir['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename( $fileurl );

if ( file_put_contents( $filename, file_get_contents( $fileurl ) ) ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
    $attachment = array(
      'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
      'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $pID );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    update_post_meta( $pID, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
}
```

Comment: file_put_contents() is not allowed on my server but I know yet how I should do it, thanks.